# Is there anything like about:healthreport in desktop Firefox browser anymore?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser, diagnostic, diagrams

Until recently, the desktop version of Firefox included a very useful internal page, `about:healthreport`.  That page presented useful information, including graphs that showed browser startup time (y-axis) vs date (x-axis).

The `about:healthreport` page is no longer available, but is there anything similar that is available, specifically to show (preferably graph) startup time vs date?

Comment: Go to `about:about` and browse what you need.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I looked through every item, but I didn't see any graph (or table) of startup time vs date.  I did find `about:telemetry`, but it seems to only show one single telemetry point at a time.